# Kafka producer in Websphere EJB: SslAuthenticationException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, websphere, kafka-producer-api, websphere-8

I am using a Websphere EJB application and I need to configure a Kafka producer. Not sure why it is throwing `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed`. We dont have any SSL certs configured but using SASL PLAIN authentication. Here is the method that set the Config properties

```
private Producer setProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "server.confluent.cloud:9092");
    props.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
    props.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"DR45F4GSVVDGT\" password=\"xxx\";");
    props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
    return producer;
}
```

I am using JDK 8 and Kafka-client-2.7. Unfortunately I need to get this working in the websphere environment. Below is the full exception. A help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[1/13/23 3:25:55:921 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
[1/13/23 3:25:55:921 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
[1/13/23 3:25:55:921 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D.z(D.java:472)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:921 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.b(aq.java:349)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:921 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.c(aq.java:304)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.wrap(aq.java:194)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:21)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeWrap(SslTransportLayer.java:478)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:341)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:173)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:563)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
[1/13/23 3:25:55:922 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:6)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:113)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:91)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:74)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:307)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:121)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D.r(D.java:223)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D$b.a(D$b.java:3)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D$b.run(D$b.java:4)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.D$c.run(D$c.java:10)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:430)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:514)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:368)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      ... 8 more
[1/13/23 3:25:55:923 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.a(f.java:107)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:108)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:4)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aB.a(aB.java:211)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aB.a(aB.java:96)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.aB.checkServerTrusted(aB.java:183)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:608)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      ... 17 more
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/13/23 3:25:55:924 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:422)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.a(f.java:74)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      ... 23 more
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:199)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:749)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:661)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:607)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:368)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      ... 25 more
[1/13/23 3:25:55:925 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/13/23 3:25:55:926 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:316)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:926 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
[1/13/23 3:25:55:926 CST] 000002f3 SystemErr     R      ... 30 more
```

**UPDATE**
As I am still struggling to find an answer let me update with what I did. First of all I could not find the certificate `CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US` which is mentioned in the exception. This certificate is nowhere in the Websphere server. Also there is no certificate configured in confluent platform. I also tried to add Websphere SSL library to set Websphere TrustStore in Kafka Producer config properties as below:

```
com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper jsseHelper = JSSEHelper.getInstance();
Properties sslProperties = jsseHelper.getProperties("default");
props.put(org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,sslProperties.getProperty("com.ibm.ssl.trustStore"));
props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");
```

but this gives me below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.security.WebSphereRuntimePermission
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
```

I am not sure if this was a solution but definitely was not helping :(

Comment: Your error is here `certificate... is not trusted`. That's unrelated to Kafka, but still interfering with its own certificate chain since you're using JAAS

Comment: And you do indeed have ssl configured - `("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where do you think I need to get it configured ? Websphere or is there anything else I need to do in Kafka configs ? Sorry Its a legacy application and I really dont have much choice but to get it worked.

Comment: Based on the stacktrace, it's a Websphere issue, which I don't have experience with, rather than Kafka

Comment: From the log you can see `CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US is not trusted` so you ARE using ssl to connect, connection is establish but cert presented by Kafka is not trusted. You have to add that cert to the WebSphere truststore, the default location would be NodeTrustStore, you will find it in the `Security > SSL certificate and key management` section of the admin console.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its confluent Kafka platform and they are using SASL_SSL with PLAIN authentication using username and password. Not using any cert there. Really stuck don't know what else I need to do. Or what cert I need to install.

Comment: @ThomsonMathew The authentication is plain (user pass) but it goes over HTTPS (SSL) and Kafka presents its SSL cert (CN=ISRG Root X1) which you have to get and add to WebSphere config. The easiest way to get it would be from WAS console form NodeTrustStore, you go to SignerCerts and do "Retrieve from port" using `server.confluent.cloud:9092` address. You can also use your browser to point to that address and save cert from browser.